# Is it possible to use a custom memory allocator for LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, memory-management

Is there a way to use a custom memory allocator for LINQ?

For example when I call:

```
someCollection.Where(x).SelectMany(y).ToList();
```

Methods like `ToList()` or `OrderBy()` will always create a new array, so lots of GC will happen.
With a custom allocator, I could always use the same List, which will be cleared and refilled every time. Iam aware that reusing buffers could lead to problems with reentrancy.

The background is, my application is a game and GC means stuttering.
Please don't tell me "Use C++ instead" or "Do not use LINQ", I know that :)

Comment: But the answer is "_Do not use LINQ_", unless you find a dirty way to swap the implementation of the Linq methods with something else. You could perhaps create your own extension method `ToPooledArray()` that is mimicking the behavior of the Linq method `Enumerable.ToArray()` (assuming `.ToArray()` is indeed a real problem for you). (P.S. Yes, there are dirty ways to replace the implementation of a method with that of another method, but doing this causes more horrible problems outweighing any potential benefits that one could ever get from such dirty shenanigans)

Comment: How about a extension method `.FillList(preallocatedList);`? Or alternatively just `myList.AddRange(<QUERY>);`

Comment: Also, it turns out `ToList()` is more performant than `ToArray()` ever so slightly. `ToArray()` requires one additional reallocation to right-size the array, where as the list's capacity doesn't need to be exact.

Comment: Your question is about ToArray but the code says ToList; can you explain the discrepancy?

Comment: @Igor: I have lots of LINQ queries scattered in my code, I query on Collections, results are normally not large. It is not time consumption of the queries that is the problem, but the memory they allocate.

Comment: Did a memory profile run show that the primary cause of collection pressure is attributable to queries? This is plausible; in early attempts at Roslyn our profiling showed that my use of LINQ in overload resolution was a significant contributor to pressure, and so we rewrote it to avoid LINQ and use pooling strategies. But we did that *after* we had a performance testing regimen in place that let us determine the size of the problem and the effect of interventions.

Comment: If you are trying to eliminate pressure and you have not first created a performance suite that clearly measures pressure and attributes it to particular allocation patterns, an attempt to fix the problem is very, very premature. You'll waste a lot of valuable time chasing down irrelevant allocations.

Comment: Static (single instance) class may be.. If you can overwrite inherited toString() you can overwrite toList() in theory..

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Sorry, my mistake, I meant ToList<>(). Custom allocation would not work good for arrays I guess, because the array length would always have to equal the results count, which would minimize reusability of a buffered array.

Comment: Do you absolutely NEED a `List`? Can you work with `IEnumerable` instead so that you stream the results of the query rather than hydrating a list?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a significant contribution to memory problems by LINQ is that LINQ encourages lambdas, which create closures, which can extend object lifetimes in surprising ways. It is very easy to accidentally close over `this` somewhere and end up keeping a network of objects alive as long as the sequence lives. In those scenarios, a `ToList` can make things *better* instead of worse because the query is realized into an object that does not contain a closure. Optimizing memory usage requires a holistic approach to empirical analysis.

Comment: `I could always use the same List` On the face of it, that sounds like a very dangerous idea. When I call `ToList` I am not expecting that the results of my **previous** `ToList` call would change.

Comment: @mjwills: Indeed, that is very dangerous. What we did in Roslyn when solving a similar problem was creating a small pool of disposable objects that could hold complex results of computations. When you want a container, you ask the pool. If the pool is empty, it creates a new object and hands it out. If not, it removes a container from the pool and returns it; when the user is done with it, they Dispose() it, and then it goes back into the pool. The objects in the pool quickly get into the gen 2 heap.

Comment: Sure, pooling can be helpful in specific circumstances - but it is hard for me to see how `ToList` could be one of them @EricLippert. There is no `Dispose` like option, so the pool is never going to be sure whether the `List` is still in use or not. _Good call in your earlier comment re: holistic analysis and closures - they are what the OP needs to focus on._

Comment: @mjwills: That's exactly right; what you'd want to do there is make an object that wraps or extends the list, and make that thing poolable. Probably one of the very few cases where deriving from `List<T>` is a reasonable choice!

Comment: Ah interesting, yeah that could work @EricLippert.

Answer (score 1):

(Although you asked not to be suggested against it, I thin this answer could help the community)

LINQ is a facility built on top the CLR, therefore it uses the CLR allocator, and it cannot be changed.
You can tune it a little bit, for example configuring whether or not the GC cycle should be offloaded to a background thread, but you can't go any further.

The aim of LINQ is to simply writing code for certain class of problems sacrificing the freedom to choose the implementation of every building block (that's why we usually choose LINQ).

However, depending on the scenario, LINQ could not be your best friend as its design choices may play against yours.
If, after profiling your code, you identify that you have a serious performance problems you should try at first to identify whether or not you can isolate the bottleneck in some of LINQ methods and see whether you can roll your own implementation, via extension methods.
Of course this option is viable when yuo are the main caller, unless you manage to roll something that is `IEnumerable` complaint. You need to be very lucky, because your implementation should abide to LINQ rules. Particularly, as you are not in control of how the objects are manipulated, you cannot perform the optimizations you would in your own code.
Closures and deferred execution work against you.

Otherwise, what has been suggested by the comments, is the only viable option: avoid using LINQ for that specific task.

The reason for stepping away from LINQ is that it is not the right tool to solve your problem with performance constraint you require.
Additionally, as stated in the comments, the (ab)use of lambda expressions significantly increase the memory pressure as backing objects are created to implement the closures.

We had performance issues similar to yours, where we had to rewrite certain slow paths. In other (rare) cases, preallocating the lists and loading the results via `AddRange` helped.